# Unable to validate while submitting form using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a form validation using jQuery. I have a problem while submitting the form. I am able to do validation of required fields only. After required field validation it automatically submitted the form, but I want to do with email field validation, alphabet validation such a things and all.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#userform').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        sex: "required",
        qualification: "required",
        email: "required",
        password: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        sex: "select gender",
        qualification: "select qualification",
        email: "enter valid email id",
        password: "Password must be required"

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        $txtfname = $('#txtfname').val()
        $txtlname = $('#txtlname').val()
        $txtemail = $('#txtemail').val()
        $txtpasswd = $('#txtpasswd').val()
        $txtcpasswd  = $('#txtcpasswd').val()
        if(!($txtfname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)))
        {
            $('.errfname').text("only alphapets");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.errfname').text("");
        }

        if(!($txtlname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)))
        {
            $('.errlname').text("only alphapets");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.errlname').text("");
        }

        $valemail = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
        if($valemail.test($txtemail))
        {
            $('.erremail').text("");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.erremail').text("Invalid email address");
        }

        if($txtpasswd != $txtcpasswd)
        {
            $('.errcpasswd').text("Password doesn't match");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.errcpasswd').text("");
        }
        form.submit();
    }



  });


 });
```

Can anyone help me to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is the submitHandler for the form will always get to form.submit();, so regardless of what comes up, if the required fields are all completed, the form will submit.

Where you have the validation within the submitHandler, you should have some way of stopping it hitting the form.submit() part if part of the validation fails.

Also, make sure you do validation on the server too, just in case the form is submitted without validation.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        var doFormSubmit = true;    
        $txtfname = $('#txtfname').val()
        $txtlname = $('#txtlname').val()
        $txtemail = $('#txtemail').val()
        $txtpasswd = $('#txtpasswd').val()
        $txtcpasswd  = $('#txtcpasswd').val()
        if(!($txtfname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)))
        {
            $('.errfname').text("only alphapets");
            doFormSubmit = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('.errfname').text("");
        }

        if(!($txtlname.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)))
        {
            $('.errlname').text("only alphapets");
            doFormSubmit = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('.errlname').text("");
        }

        $valemail = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
        if($valemail.test($txtemail))
        {
            $('.erremail').text("");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.erremail').text("Invalid email address");
            doFormSubmit = false;
        }

        if($txtpasswd != $txtcpasswd)
        {
            $('.errcpasswd').text("Password doesn't match");
            doFormSubmit = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('.errcpasswd').text("");
        }
        if (doFormSubmit)
        {
            form.submit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I jus want to stop submission form if validation failed... yes it always submitting the form directly.. what i have to change in that code..

Comment: I'd add a variable to the submitHandler part, something like var doFormSubmit = true;  Whenever the validation fails, set that to false, and then check, just before the form.submit() part, that the variable is true.  Submit if it is, and fail it if not.  I'll add the code to my answer